# VBA if in text is in textbox then do something

Tags: vba, excel

I've written the following code so that if a certain text exists in my listbox and "ok" button is clicked a certain thing is done.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

If (Me.ListBox2.Text) <> ("PA") Then

Call macro1

ElseIf (Me.ListBox2.Text) <> "menu" Then

Sheets("menu").Visible = xlSheetVisible

Worksheets("menu").Activate

Else
 MsgBox "Nothing is selected"

End If 

End Sub
```

The problem is that when "ok" is clicked all events are still carried out even if the specified text isn't in the textbox.

Comment: `<>` is **not equal to** operator. In other words, `<>` is not **equal to** operator.

Comment: I tried replacing it with an "=" operator but now I get "Nothing is selected" as an output no matter which text is in the textbox.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Textbox?  Or Listbox?

Comment: Apologies, Listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `=` operator, and not `<>` operator. Also note that `ListBox.List(i)` is the correct way of getting selected item for single selection mode:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
  Dim SelectedItem = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)

  If SelectedItem = "PA" Then   
    Call macro1    
  ElseIf SelectedItem = "menu" Then  
    Sheets("menu").Visible = xlSheetVisible    
    Worksheets("menu").Activate    
  Else
    MsgBox "Nothing is selected"    
  End If     
End Sub
```

### Edit

Following your comment, you can create a function that looks for the existence of that item:

```
Private Function TextExists(text as String) as Boolean
  Dim i as Long
  For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.List(i) = text Then
      TextExists = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  TextExists = False
End Function
```

And then use this function in the main code like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
  If TextExists("PA") Then   
    Call macro1    
  ElseIf TextExists("menu") Then  
    Sheets("menu").Visible = xlSheetVisible    
    Worksheets("menu").Activate    
  Else
    MsgBox "Nothing is selected"    
  End If     
End Sub
```

N.B. I have written this manually here, without an IDE. Please check for indexes and other little things.

Comment: This works if the text is selected but I want it so that if the text "exists" in the listbox then do something.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfect. Just missing " Dim i as Integer " at the top.

Comment: @AIS Use `Dim i As Long` rather than `Dim i As Integer`.  (Excel uses `Long` data types internally now, so it reduces the need for a lot of implicit type conversions.)